# Excel vba: Salvando dados de uma planilha no formato .txt

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Boa tarde. Tenho a macro abaixo e ela já faz quase o que eu quero (cria um arquivo txt com os dados da planilha Historico, sempre reescrevendo o arquivo, ou seja, não cria varias copias), porém essa planilha Historico, contem nomes de times de futebol e ao encontrar nomes estranhos tipo: "Śląsk Wrocław , Górnik Łęczna , Wisła Płock" a macro trava e aparece a mensagem: Erro em tempo de execução '5': Argumento ou chamada de procedimento inválida

Option Explicit

Sub CrearTXT()

```
'tem que ativar a referência => Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Dim NombreArchivo, RutaArchivo As String
Dim obj As FileSystemObject
Dim tx As Scripting.TextStream
Dim Ht As Worksheet
Dim i, j, nFilas, nColumnas As Integer

NombreArchivo = "Batch"
RutaArchivo = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & NombreArchivo & ".txt"

Set Ht = Worksheets("Historico")
Set obj = New FileSystemObject
Set tx = obj.CreateTextFile(RutaArchivo)

nColumnas = Ht.Range("A1", Ht.Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Cells.Count
nFilas = Ht.Range("A2", Ht.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count

For i = 1 To nFilas

    If Ht.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value <> "" Then

    For j = 1 To nColumnas
        tx.write Ht.Cells(i + 1, j).Value  'É nesta parte onde a macro trava
        If j < nColumnas Then tx.write "|"
    Next j

    tx.writeLine

    End If

Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: Veja [este site](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)

Comment: E [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/286876/75104) tem uma parte de salvar em arquivo txt com codificação UTF-8, com esta codificação estes erros irão desaparecer.

Answer (score 1):

Se você não se importar que esses nomes não entrem em seu txt você pode simplesmente adicionar no inicio do código:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

Se o caso não for esse, tente rever o método que esta usando para escrever no txt, eu uso geralmente

```
Print #1, "Texto qualquer"
```

Podemos conversar mais, qualquer coisa.

Comment: Bom dia Leandro. Esse nomes tem que entra, pois são os nomes dos times. como eu "encaixaria" o código: Print #1, "Texto qualquer" no código que já tenho? esse código acima esta no ponto que quero, apenas com essa falha em relação a letras de outro alfabetos