# VBA - Erro: O método 'frames' do objeto 'JScriptTypeInfo' falhou

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Preciso preencher a caixinhavda aba 'Legislação' com o texto "Conta de Desenvolvimento Energético" e fazer a pesquisa. Mas ao executar o código aparece o erro citado no título referente a linha "obj = IE.doc[...]".

```
'Declara função Sleep
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If

Sub CDE_ANEEL()

    Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.navigate "http://biblioteca.aneel.gov.br/index.html"
    IE.Visible = True

    Sleep 2000

obj = IE.document.frames(0).document.getEmelementByTagName("input")

i = 0

Do While i < obj.Length
    If obj(i).Name = "leg_campo1" Then
    obj(i).Value = "Conta de Desenvolvimento Energético"
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

O que devo fazer para corrigir isso?

obs: Daniel, fiz estas mudanças. Ele preenche a caixa, mas não consigo fazer o clique. Tem algum erro no código?

```
    Set doc = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(0).contentDocument.body
    Set doc1 = doc.getElementsByClassName("inputLegEsq")
    Set doc2 = doc.getElementsByClassName("button_busca")
```

For Each el In doc1
       'Debug.Print el.Name, el.Value
       If el.Name = "leg_campo1" Then el.Value = "Conta de Desenvolvimento Energético"
       Next el

Sleep 2000

```
'Apertar Botão
```

For Each el In doc2
        Debug.Print el.Title, el.onclick
        Debug.Print InStr(1, el.onclick, "Confere(5613,5,'',parent.hiddenFrame.modo_busca)")
        If InStr(1, el.onclick, "Confere(5613,5,'',parent.hiddenFrame.modo_busca)") > 0 Then el.Click
    Next el

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT:

Este código funciona do mesmo jeito que o outro, mas antes clica na aba Legislação. Sugiro utilizar o código que gera o txt com o html para testar esta aplicação. E aprender sobre o DOM.

```
Sub CDE_ANEEL()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As Object, doc1 As Object, doc2 As Object, aba As Object
    Dim el

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.navigate "http://biblioteca.aneel.gov.br/index.html"
    IE.Visible = True
    EsperaIE IE, 2500
    Set doc = IE.document.getElementsbyTagName("frame")(0).contentdocument.body
    Set doc1 = doc.getElementsbyClassName("inputLegEsq")
    Set doc2 = doc.getElementsbyClassName("button_busca")
    Set aba = doc.getElementsbyClassName("text-aba")

    For Each el In aba
        'Debug.Print el.InnerText
        If el.InnerText = "Legislação" Then el.Click
    Next el

    For Each el In doc1
        'Debug.Print el.Name, el.Value
        If el.Name = "leg_campo1" Then
       el.Value = "Conta de Desenvolvimento Energético"
       el.InnerText = "Conta de Desenvolvimento Energético"
       el.Focus
        End If
    Next el

    'Aperta Enter
    Sleep 5000

    Application.SendKeys ("~"), True

End Sub
```

A utilização de button.Click não está sendo possível por causa do código JavaScript de value onchange, que não está reconhecendo a alteração no campo enquanto não houver interação com o teclado.

## Resposta Original

## Código

```
'Declara função Sleep
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If

Sub CDE_ANEEL()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As Object, doc1 As Object, doc2 As Object
    Dim sFilename As String, sFilepath As String
    Dim objStream As Object
    Dim strData As String
    Dim el

    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    sFilename = "temp.txt"
    sFilepath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sFilename

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.navigate "http://biblioteca.aneel.gov.br/index.html"
    IE.Visible = True
    EsperaIE IE, 2500
        Set doc = IE.document.getElementsbyTagName("frame")(0).contentdocument.body
        Set doc1 = doc.getElementsbyClassName("input_busca")
        Set doc2 = doc.getElementsbyClassName("button_busca")

    For Each el In doc1
        'Debug.Print el.Name, el.Value
        If el.Name = "rapida_campo" Then el.Value = "Conta de Desenvolvimento Energético"
    Next el

    'Aperta Enter
    Sleep 5000
    Application.SendKeys ("~"), True

'    'Apertar Botão
'    For Each el In doc2
''        Debug.Print el.Title, el.onclick
''        Debug.Print InStr(1, el.onclick, "Confere(5613,1,'','rapida')")
'        If InStr(1, el.onclick, "Confere(5613,1,'','rapida')") > 0 Then el.Click
'    Next el

'        'Cria arquivo txt com o HTML para Debug
'        Debug.Print IE.document.getElementsbyTagName("frame")(0).contentdocument.body.innerHTML
'
'        objStream.Type = 2                           'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.
'        objStream.Charset = "utf-8"                  'Specify charset For the source text data.
'        objStream.Open                               'Open the stream And write binary data To the object
'        objStream.WriteText doc.innerHTML
'        objStream.SaveToFile sFilepath, 2            'Save binary data To disk
'        'close down IE and reset status bar
'        objStream.Close
'    IE.Quit
'    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
Public Sub EsperaIE(IE As Object, Optional time As Long = 250)
'Código de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808000/run-time-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set
Dim i As Long
Do
    Sleep time
    Debug.Print CStr(i) & vbTab & "Ready: " & CStr(IE.READYSTATE = 4) & _
                vbCrLf & vbTab & "Busy: " & CStr(IE.Busy)
    i = i + 1
Loop Until IE.READYSTATE = 4 Or Not IE.Busy
End Sub
```

## Explicação

> Este código possui um código em baixo, que você gera um arquivo .txt
>   com o código HTML, para você testar e aprender mais sobre DOM e
>   hierarquia de sites. Teste em outras aplicações...

#### 1 - Doc

Primeiro você encontra a iFrame e depois o Body dentro dessa Frame com `Set doc = IE.document.getElementsbyTagName("frame")(0).contentdocument.body`

#### 2 - Doc1

Depois a Class input_busca é atribuída a doc1 `Set doc1 = doc.getElementsbyClassName("input_busca")`

#### 3 - Doc2

Depois a Class button_busca é atribuída a doc1 `Set doc1 = doc.getElementsbyClassName("button_busca")`

#### 4 - Preenche campo

Depois o campo de busca é preenchido, para encontrá-lo, todas as class input_busca são encontradas, mas a que possui o nome igual a rapida_campo é preenchida.

```
For Each el In doc1
    'Debug.Print el.Name, el.Value
    If el.Name = "rapida_campo" Then el.Value = "Conta de Desenvolvimento Energético"
Next el
```

#### 5 - Aperta tecla enter

Espera 5 segundos e aperta a tecla Enter. Portanto, não pode minimizar ou fechar a janela do IE.
Ao clicar no botão com o outro código, um erro ocorria.

```
Sleep 5000
Application.SendKeys ("~"), True
```

#### Mais explicações:

As explicações mais detalhadas das outras funções já foram dadas [neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/285054/75104)

Comment: Daniel, eu não especifiquei na pergunta (já reeditei), mas a caixa de texto é a da aba de 'Legislação', por causa disso o Enter não funciona. Vou tentar mudar o código para apertar da outra forma que colocou aqui

Comment: Daniel, o que quer dizer "Confere(5613,3,'','rapida')") ?

Comment: Você encontra vários botões com este código: `<input name="bt_comb" tabindex="20" title="Submeter busca" class="button_busca" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" onclick="return Confere(5613,5,'',parent.hiddenFrame.modo_busca)" type="button" value="Buscar">` ou `<input name="bt_comb" title="Submeter busca" class="button_busca" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" onclick="return Confere(5613,3,'','rapida')" type="button" value="Buscar">` e este é o parâmetro dentro das aspas "" de onclick.

Comment: Adicionei a alteração do código na pergunta. Mas não consegui fazer o clique.

Comment: Daniel, eu tinha alterado o código e consegui mudar o texto mesmo sem abrir a aba, mas surgiu outro problema. Estou descrevendo ele em outra pergunta para não sobrecarregar esta. se puder dar uma olhada te agradeço!

Comment: Não achei uma maneira de realizar isto sem clicar na aba. Pois a utilização de button.Click não está sendo possível por causa do código JavaScript de value onchange, que não está reconhecendo a alteração no campo enquanto não houver interação com o teclado.